# Регулярное выражение с переменным количеством знака в парных кавчках

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Каким образом можно выделить с помощью RE знак восклицания (!), стоящий **n-раз** в парных кавычках?
Например, есть выражение **qwe"!"asdas2.53** 
Если известно сколько раз у меня будет стоять в парных кавычках знак восклицания, то это не составляет особого труда. 
А вот как сделать, чтобы выражение срабатывало и для выше написанного и например для такого: **qwe"!!!!!"as"!!!!!!!!!!"das2.53** (то-есть там где количество знака восклицание заранее не известно).
То что успел написать: ***^([-_a-z0-9]+(.)?("!")*){1,128}$***
Заранее благодарю!
п/с - рэ 1ый день изучаю, сильно не ругайте =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Каким образом можно выделить с помощью RE знак восклицания (!), стоящий n-раз в парных кавычках?

```
"!+"
```

> Дано слово, нужно проверить, чтобы кавычки " - были только парными, а знаки (восклицания (!),запятая (,), двоеточ (:)) находились только в этих парных кавчках

```
^([^"!,:]|"[^"]*")*$
```

Comment: Дак в этом случае я так понимаю он будет ожидать именно "!+", а не n-знаков ! в ""...

Comment: @АлександрРыбаков, не понимаю.

Comment: прошу прощения))все оказалось еще проще, чем думал) вы были правы, спасибо!

Comment: Такой вопрос еще, к примеру если мне необходимо проверить не 1 знак (!), а 3 (!,запятая, двоеточие). Для двух символов вроде получилось такое - не самое красивое выражение -  ^([-_a-z0-9]+(\.)?(("!*|:*|!*")|(":*|!*|:*")|"")*){1,128}$ . Не могу понять, как лучше сделать переделать?  ^([-_a-z0-9]+(\.)?(("!*|:*|,*")|("!*|,*|:*")|(":*|!*|,*")|(":*|,*|!*")|(",*|:*|!*")|(",*|!*|:*")|"")*){1,128}$

Comment: @АлександрРыбаков, снова непонятно...

Comment: Хорошо, попытаюсь более понятно объяснить. Дано слово, нужно проверить, чтобы кавычки " - были только парными, а знаки (восклицания (!),запятая (,), двоеточ (:)) находились только в этих парных кавчках

Comment: @АлександрРыбаков, ответ дополнен.